# highlight closest/farthest value to zero

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need to find a way to highlight closes and farthest value to/from 0 in my excel table. I know easiest way to achieve it is by using conditional formatting, however I can not do it correctly even with help of tutorials. Based on this site:

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4095-excel-highlight-closest-value.html

i used formula

`=ABS(A2-$D$2)=MIN(ABS($A$2:$A$15-$D$2))` on my test data but it dosent work... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You will need to show your test data.  It works for me.

Comment: I didnt explain clearly what problem Im having here.
Here is the file - `https://ufile.io/xst6v`. I want to apply this formule to entire table like in 3rd sheet (or to each row separately).

Answer (score 0):

I would add a helper column that is absolute value of difference. Then add another cell that's min of that column. Will make it easier to debug.

Answer (score -1):

This issue was related to my system exclusively. Worked on other computer. Got new system and this problem never occurred again.